# Listing with monospaced font (Dejavu Sans Mono) and background color

Tags: fonts, listings, color

I will setup my document to the Sans Serif Font `Helvet` and additionally all source codes should display with `Dejavu Sans Mono` and grey background color (on `\lstinline{}` too). How can I setup `listings` correctly to do so?

```
\documentclass[idxtotoc,hyperref,openany,ngerman,11pt]{article} 
\usepackage[a4paper,
            inner=30mm, outer=20mm,
            top=25mm, bottom=25mm,
            headheight=15mm, headsep=7mm
            ]{geometry}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,cancel,icomma,nicefrac,mathrsfs,
            eurosym,verbatim,environ,ifthen,ifdraft,pdfpages,float,booktabs}
\allowdisplaybreaks[1] 

\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{lstgrey}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.95}
\usepackage{dejavu}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=C,
       backgroundcolor=\color{lstgrey},
       frame=single,
       basicstyle=\footnotesize\sf,
       captionpos=b,
       tabsize=2,
  }

\begin{document}
An example listing shows the \lstinline|main()|:

\begin{lstlisting}[caption=main.c]
int main (void)
{
  return 0;
};
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Using `colorbox` and a new command I get the inline listing with a background:

```
\newcommand\code[1]{\colorbox{lstgrey}{{\lstinline`#1`}}}
...
An example listing shows the \code{main()}:
```

[image]

---

Final code with thanks to AboAmmar:

```
\documentclass[hyperref,ngerman,11pt]{article} 
\usepackage[a4paper,
            inner=30mm, outer=20mm,
            top=25mm, bottom=25mm,
            headheight=15mm, headsep=7mm
            ]{geometry}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{dejavu}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,cancel,icomma,
            nicefrac,mathrsfs,eurosym,verbatim,environ,
            ifthen,ifdraft,pdfpages,float,booktabs}
\allowdisplaybreaks[1] 

\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{lstgrey}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.95}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=C,
       backgroundcolor=\color{lstgrey},
       frame=single,
       basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
       captionpos=b,
       tabsize=2,
  }
\newcommand\code[1]{\colorbox{lstgrey}{{\lstinline`#1`}}}

\begin{document}
An example listing shows the \code{main()}:

\begin{lstlisting}[caption=main.c]
int main (void)
{
  return 0;
};
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: How to set-up listings that listing are displayed with Dejavu Sans Mono?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Helvetica` for main body and `Dejavu Sans Mono` for listings, right? OK, observe this line `basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,` with that `\ttfamily` at the end. In your post you used the `\sf` which was the reason for not getting the `Dejavu Sans Mono` but still getting `Dejavu Sans` for every thing. You also issued the command `\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}` which confirmed this.

```
\documentclass[hyperref,ngerman,11pt]{article} 
\usepackage[a4paper,
            inner=30mm, outer=20mm,
            top=25mm, bottom=25mm,
            headheight=15mm, headsep=7mm
            ]{geometry}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{dejavu}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,cancel,icomma,nicefrac,mathrsfs,
            eurosym,verbatim,environ,ifthen,ifdraft,pdfpages,float,booktabs}
\allowdisplaybreaks[1] 

\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{lstgrey}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.95}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=C,
       backgroundcolor=\color{lstgrey},
       frame=single,
       basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
       captionpos=b,
       tabsize=2,
  }

\begin{document}
An example listing shows the \lstinline|main()|:

\begin{lstlisting}[caption=main.c]
int main (void)
{
  return 0;
};
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\ttfamily`, please

Comment: Why you can say, thar `ttfamily` is linked to DejaVu and not to Helvetia?

Comment: @Alex44  - The `helvet` package loads only the **sans serif** font known as `Helvetica` and it must be activated using, e.g., `\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv}` to be used for the **sans serif** parts of your text. It doesn't have a **typewriter** font, however ([see this link](https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2Fmirrors.ctan.org%2Fmacros%2Flatex%2Frequired%2Fpsnfss%2Fpsnfss2e.pdf)). The `dejavu`, on the other hand, has all font shapes ([compare this](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/dejavumono/)).

Comment: @AboAmmar This means that this way don't work with other fonts whish provide typewriter fonts too (instead of `helvet`).

Comment: @Alex44  - If both fonts have a **typewriter** shape, then the one loaded last will be selected. To see this, try to replace `helvet` with `bookman`, you will find `courier` is selected for `ttfamily`