# specify exact font for lstlisting

Tags: fonts, listings, lstlisting

I am writing a document in Latex (pdflatex) and I am bound to use a predefined custom style. Now, I want/need to print a code listing using `\lstlisting`, which I need to be monospaced sans-serif.

My problem is now, that listings I create are monospaced, but NOT sans-serif. Whatever I try, my listings end up being serif. And I need to change that.

The style is extensive (more than 1500 lines) and must not be altered, hence pasting it in its entirety is I guess not helping.

Anyhow I went though it and think I identified the interesting parts:

```
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage{lmodern,textcomp}
\RequirePackage{microtype}
\RequirePackage[ngerman]{babel}
\RequirePackage{ae,pifont}              
\Requirepackage{courier}

% ...

\usepackage{listings}
\lstloadlanguages{
    [Visual]Basic,
    Pascal,
    C,
    [ISO]C++,
    XML,
    HTML,
    Java,
    bash
}
\lstset{
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    upquote=true,
    keepspaces=true,
    language=Java,
    numbers=none,
    numbersep=5pt,
    tabsize=2,
    extendedchars=true,
    breaklines=true,
    basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily\color{basicStyleColor},
    identifierstyle=\color{identifierStyleColor},
    keywordstyle=[1]\color{keywordStyle1Color},
    keywordstyle=[2]\color{keywordStyle2Color},
    keywordstyle=[3]\color{keywordStyle3Color},
    stringstyle=\color{stringStyleColor},
    commentstyle=\itshape\color{commentStyleColor},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{commentStyleColor},
    rulecolor=\color{black},
    showspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,
    xleftmargin=17pt,
    frame=none,
    framexleftmargin=17pt,
    %framexrightmargin=5pt,
    framexbottommargin=4pt,
    %backgroundcolor=\color{lightgray},
    showstringspaces=false,
      {á}{{\'a}}1 {é}{{\'e}}1 {í}{{\'i}}1 {ó}{{\'o}}1 {ú}{{\'u}}1
      {Á}{{\'A}}1 {É}{{\'E}}1 {Í}{{\'I}}1 {Ó}{{\'O}}1 {Ú}{{\'U}}1
      {à}{{\`a}}1 {è}{{\`e}}1 {ì}{{\`i}}1 {ò}{{\`o}}1 {ù}{{\`u}}1
      {À}{{\`A}}1 {È}{{\'E}}1 {Ì}{{\`I}}1 {Ò}{{\`O}}1 {Ù}{{\`U}}1
      {ä}{{\"a}}1 {ë}{{\"e}}1 {ï}{{\"i}}1 {ö}{{\"o}}1 {ü}{{\"u}}1
      {Ä}{{\"A}}1 {Ë}{{\"E}}1 {Ï}{{\"I}}1 {Ö}{{\"O}}1 {Ü}{{\"U}}1
      {â}{{\^a}}1 {ê}{{\^e}}1 {î}{{\^i}}1 {ô}{{\^o}}1 {û}{{\^u}}1
      {Â}{{\^A}}1 {Ê}{{\^E}}1 {Î}{{\^I}}1 {Ô}{{\^O}}1 {Û}{{\^U}}1
      {œ}{{\oe}}1 {Œ}{{\OE}}1 {æ}{{\ae}}1 {Æ}{{\AE}}1 {ß}{{\ss}}1
      {ű}{{\H{u}}}1 {Ű}{{\H{U}}}1 {ő}{{\H{o}}}1 {Ő}{{\H{O}}}1
      {ç}{{\c c}}1 {Ç}{{\c C}}1 {ø}{{\o}}1 {å}{{\r a}}1 {Å}{{\r A}}1
      {€}{{\euro}}1 {£}{{\pounds}}1 {«}{{\guillemotleft}}1
      {»}{{\guillemotright}}1 {ñ}{{\~n}}1 {Ñ}{{\~N}}1 {¿}{{?`}}1
      {€}{{\texteuro}}1
}
```

with the document preamble being

```
\documentclass[12pt]{mystyle}

\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\begin{document}
    \sloppy
```

Now, I want to print something like this and want it to be in sans-serif font:

```
\begin{lstlisting}
import akka.actor.{ActorSystem, Props}

object Main extends App {
}
\end{lstlisting}
```

But no matter what I do, the font always remains the same for the listings.

How do I change the font for the listings (Meaning: not just the font-family (\tttype), but the entire font?) while at the same time NOT changing the font for the rest of the document?

Comment: Which font do you want to use? Unrelated: don't use the ae package, that it quite unneeded today.

Comment: I was thinking arial, but since this is not a standard font, i would go for droid sans

Comment: Neither arial nor droid sans is a monospaced font.

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/413586/how-to-get-a-monospaced-sans-serif-font-for-the-source-code-when-using-lstinputl ?

Comment: Or maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/297483/listing-with-monospaced-font-dejavu-sans-mono-and-background-color , also monospaced and sans serif.

Comment: Or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174892/what-is-the-least-invasive-way-to-set-the-font-for-listings for a different approach without font packages.

Comment: then about any monospaced, non-serif font for the listings, but another, serif-font for the text. possible?

Comment: @Xenonite that is possible, all three questions in my previous comments have different fonts for the listings and the main text, in the first and third linked question the main font is serif.